# Postgresql JSON using WITH RECURSIVE

Tags: json, common-table-expression, postgresql-11, postgresql-12

My json is

```
[
  {
    "id": null,
    "st": "value1",
    "key": 1,
    "value": "i am calling from",
    "description": null
  },
  {
    "st": "value2",
    "key": 5,
    "value": "i am calling from",
    "description": null
  },

  {
    "id": 25,
    "st": "value3",
    "key": 1,
    "value": "i am calling from",
    "description": null
  }
]
```

I need to iterate the id (only when it is null and no id key) with a number and form back the same json as below even though the key (id) is missing . It has to be automatic id generation because I never know how many elements are present in this aggregation.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "st": "value1",
    "key": 1,
    "value": "i am calling from",
    "description": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "st": "value2",
    "key": 5,
    "value": "i am calling from",
    "description": null
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "st": "value3",
    "key": 1,
    "value": "i am calling from",
    "description": null
  }
]
```

I believe RECURSIVE CTE work, but I'm unable to find a way to work this out. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You could unnest the array and replace any null value for `id` with the array index. However, this does not guarantee unique IDs as there could be an array index that is already used.

```
select jsonb_agg(
          case 
            when t.d ->> 'id' is null then t.d||jsonb_build_object('id', t.idx)
            else t.d
          end
       )
from jsonb_array_elements('[
  {
    "id": null,
    "st": "value1",
    "key": 1,
    "value": "i am calling from",
    "description": null
  },
  {
    "st": "value2",
    "key": 5,
    "value": "i am calling from",
    "description": null
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "st": "value3",
    "key": 1,
    "value": "i am calling from",
    "description": null
  }
]'::jsonb) with ordinality as t(d,idx)
```